# Add $LOAD_PATH externally

Tags: ruby, load-path

I understand that to add a path to $LOAD_PATH just do

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(path)
```

But I have to add this line to every program I wrote. Is there anyway to add it to the system level?

I tried to search a bit on the startup script for Ruby, but did not find the answer. I tried to add this line to `kernel/common/module.rb`, `ruby_constants.rb`, `loader.rb`,etc. but neither works.

In which file should I add this line to?

---

Updates:

I am using ubuntu 10.04 and Rubinius. There is no system variable called `RUBYLIB`.

Tried creating one but did not work. But I realize I made a mistake, and forgot to add the variable in bash script `.bashrc`. After adding the variable, it all works fine!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`RUBYLIB` environment variable is a colon separated list of paths which ruby will prepend to the standard LOAD_PATH. `ruby -I path` on the command line is also the same as `$LOAD_PATH.unshift 'path'` in your code. Ruby will also process options from environment var RUBYOPT.

Comment: I thought they removed RUBYLIB after 1.9? I am using Rubinius and did not find RUBYLIB. And ruby -I is annoying too

Comment: I just double checked. There is no RUBYLIB or RUBYOPT env var. I am using ubuntu 10.04 and Rubinius 2.0. I also tried adding a system variable but it did not work.

Comment: @texasbruce maybe you should edit your question to show what you tried, and how it didn't work.

Comment: @texasbruce rbx honors RUBYLIB just as MRI rubies do.  Here's the [source](https://github.com/dbenhur/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/loader.rb#L115)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ export RUBYLIB=/tmp/test
$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > puts $LOAD_PATH
/tmp/test
...
```