# Addind new directory to $LOAD_PATH in Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-12.04

Having gone through several posts on this issue I still can't add new directory to `$LOAD_PATH`. I use Ubuntu 12. My `$LOAD_PATH` is:

```
2.0.0-p247 :002 > puts $LOAD_PATH
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
 => nil
```

How to add '`/home/ajax/Ruby/Projects`' to `$LOAD_PATH` through terminal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add $LOAD\_PATH eternally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117125/add-load-path-eternally)

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional entries to the `$LOAD_PATH` as a command line parameter to your `ruby` (or `irb`) command using the `-I` argument (which can be used multiple times)

```
$ ruby -I '/home/ajax/Ruby/Projects' -e 'puts $LOAD_PATH'
/home/ajax/Ruby/Projects
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0
/home/ajax/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wonder whether I should execute the same command each time I open terminal. Can I change $LOAD_PATH permanently?

Comment: The default `$LOAD_PATH` is compiled into your ruby. Using the -I parameter, you can add a new path to the newly started ruby process. It will not be persisted that way. Generally, you should probably start to use rubygems instead of messing with the LOAD_PATH by hand.

Answer (score 0):

in your terminal

```
export RUBYLIB=/home/ajax/Ruby/Projects
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wonder if I can add new directory permanently. After executing export RUBYLIB=/home/ajax/Ruby/Projects new directory was added successfully but after reopening terminal it's disappeared.

Comment: you can add this line to .bashrc

Comment: For me it's working:) So maybe your .bashrc also not loaded automaticly.
The standard ~/.profile has this:

"if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi"
check it maybe you haven't

Answer (score 0):

From [Add $LOAD_PATH externally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117125/add-load-path-eternally)

> `RUBYLIB` environment variable is a colon separated list of paths which ruby will prepend the the standard LOAD_PATH. `ruby -I path` on the command line is also the same as `$LOAD_PATH.unshift 'path'` in your code. Ruby will also process options from environment var RUBYOPT.